# Setting up IQueryable model in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository, database

I have a problem with my `IRepository`, which looks like this:

```
public interface IArticleRepository
{
    IQueryable<Article> Articles { get; }

    void SaveArticle(Article article);

    void EditArticle(Article article);

    void DeleteArticle(Article article);

}
```

and my Communication Class:

```
public class Communication: IArticleRepository
{

    public IQueryable<Article> Articles { 
        get 
        {
            return articles.AsQueryable<Article>; 
        } 
    }


    public void SaveArticle(Article Article)
    {
    }

    public void EditArticle(Article Article)
    {
    }

    public void DeleteArticle(Article Article)
    {
    }
```

I don't have idea how to implement this `IQueryable` so this could work.

Any ideas?